# how to edit a url obtained from user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that asks a user to input a URL and append it to a div using javascript and it works fine. what I was trying to add was editing the user entered URL, specifically change the width and height of the iframe entered by the user then appending it. My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function input() {
         globalThis.urlInput = prompt("Enter embed URL:");
        if ( urlInput == "") {
            alert("No URL Inputted");
        } else {
           appendUrl();
        }
    }
    
  function appendUrl(){
    document.getElementById("add_to_me").innerHTML += urlInput;
          document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').width= "300px";
          document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').height= "300px";
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="input()">Input</button>

<div id="add_to_me"></div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a form with multiple input elements to allow the user to pass the width and height, and the URL?

Comment: It's going to be the same though. Let us say the user entered an iframe embed  "<iframe width="1263" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XW_KhFq4LQo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> '' and then you ask the user to input their desired width and height, you are going to have to edit the URL the user inputted.@EmielZuurbier

Comment: I understand. So it's not a URL but an iframe tag. Consider this: if you allow the user to enter the URL, width and height separately, for example `https://www.youtube.com/embed/XW_KhFq4LQo`, `1263` and `480`, then you could build the iframe with those values instead of modifying an existing iframe that is just a string. Is that something that you would prefer?

Comment: That's actually smart. Thanks for the help. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: You got it. Do you need help working that out?

Comment: Nope, Got some same suggestion below as an answer to that should be enough. @EmielZuurbier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do;

```js
function input() {
    globalThis.urlInput="";
    urlInput = prompt("Enter embed URL:");
    if ( urlInput == "") {
        alert("No URL Inputted");
    } else {
       appendUrl();
    }
}
    
function appendUrl(){
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src",urlInput );
    ifrm.style.width = "300px";
    ifrm.style.height = "300px";
    ifrm.style.frameborder = "0";
    ifrm.allowFullScreen = true;
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="input()">Input</button>
```

Comment: is there any way to add other attributes to the iframe like frameborder and allow fullscreen?@Zoldxk

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I do is I create the iframes dynamically and prompt multiple times for url, width and height which I then set on the newly created iframe DOM-Element.

As far as I know it is generally considered bad practice to use global variables. So I edited your code to inject the user input from user function `input()` into
`appendiFrame(input)`.

Here's my extended code (consider the comments):

```js
function input() {
        // create local variable
        var input = { url: '', width: '0', height: '0'} // creates dictionary containing input

        input.url = prompt("Enter embed URL:")
        if ( input.url == "") { // test if url was given
            alert("No URL Inputted")
            return // return if empty
        }

        input.width = prompt("Enter width:")
        input.height = prompt("Enter height:")
        appendiFrame(input)
    }
    
  function appendiFrame(input){
      iframe = document.createElement('iframe') // create iframe dynamically
      iframe.src = input.url;
      iframe.width= input.width
      iframe.height= input.height
      document.getElementById('add_to_me').appendChild(iframe)
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="input()">Input</button>

<div id="add_to_me"></div>
```

In order to test it you need to also enter the protocol (`https`) as part of the url. The site also must not send the `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` HTTP-header as e.g. Google does or else your browser won't load the iframe.

You might also perform some checking whether the inputs entered are valid.